# Do smart contract transactions get signed?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, signature

When you send a transaction to a smart contract by using the contract.methods.methodName().send() is it signed by the sender?  If not how can I link the sender to that transaction call

Answer (score 0):

Like any other transaction from accounts, yes.
Otherwise, I could send out a transaction in the network claiming that you've interacted with my contract and nobody could verify you did not. That's why every tx needs to have a valid signature with it.